# MariaDB - How to join a table on a specific value that is in a list of other values

Tags: mariadb

I have a stored routine that accepts a comma delimited string, splits the values, and returns a list of those values.

I now need to perform a join where a value is in that returned list of values.

So, I have the following, but obviously my logic is incorrect:

```
SELECT 
    A.* 
  , B.*
FROM TableA A
LEFT JOIN TableB B ON
    B.ID IN (CALL spSplitString(A.IDs));
```

So how do I join `B.ID` on the result of `spSplitString`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need not stored procedure here. You can use builtin function FIND_IN_SET:

```
SELECT 
    A.* 
  , B.*
FROM TableA A
LEFT JOIN TableB B ON FIND_IN_SET(B.ID, A.IDs);
```

[MariaDB fiddle](https://sqlize.online/?phpses=null&sqlses=562f6661abf58acf21677ceaa9dc0457&php_version=null&sql_version=mysql57)

Comment: Even though the answer does work, it is not a feasible solution for large tables as `FIND_IN_SET` does a full table scan of the data. So performance wise not good.